# Android webview eclipse throwing error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-chrome, webview

I have problem with starting [this](https://github.com/tscolari/android-webview-sample-app) project under eclipse. After run in debug tab I see this error message

```
Thread [Chrome_InProcGpuThread] (Suspended (exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException))    
    dalvik.system.PathClassLoader(java.lang.ClassLoader).loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) line: 514 
    dalvik.system.PathClassLoader(java.lang.ClassLoader).loadClass(java.lang.String) line: 469
```

In android studio it works properly, it means code is correct. Seems to be problem with dependencies, but I'm not sure.

And same error I see in another production project with webview. How to fix it?

P.S. I need to use only eclipse, because another major project is using eclipse (jni). Code above I posted for sample. It's same error.

Comment: it is a missing package. how did you build this on Android Studio? Did you have a gradle file?

Comment: also in your manifest, include a targetSDK